# Is there a fast way to add squares (or other functions) of every input feature without specifying them explicitly in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear regression, and I would like to consider all the input features as well as their squares. For a simple linear regression, I can just do

```
lm(y~.,data=MyData)
```

For a data set with a small number of variables, I can do

```
lm(y~poly(x1,2)+poly(x2,2), data=myData)
```

However,  if I have a lot of input features, how can I do this concisely, without explicitly listing every feature? I tried the following but it resulted in a syntax error.

```
lm(y~poly(.,2), data=myData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a formula by constructing the appropriate string:

```
formula_string = paste(sprintf('y ~ poly(1,%d)', 1:2), collapse = " + ")
formula_string
[1] "y ~ poly(1,1) + y ~ poly(1,2)"
as.formula(formula_string)
y ~ poly(1, 1) + y ~ poly(1, 2)

lm(as.formula(formula_string), data = myData)
```

Note that using `as.formula` is not needed perse, `lm` would cast the string to a formula if needed.